# How can I create a blocking dialog in javafx swt mixed application?

Tags: java, javafx, swt, controlsfx

I am creating an application which is a mixed application of swt and fx .So to embed Fx controls i am using FX canvas. As per my understanding the fx dialog can be set  block-able when I set the stage as its parent and set its initmodality.I had given try to Controlfx dialog also where I was setting the owner a a stackpane which is  my parent after fxcanvas.But the dialog is still going to background when I click on the application screen .Any help on this will be appreciated .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can write our own dialog by extending  JFACE dialog and overriding Control createDialogArea(Composite parent) to create FXCanvas and other FX Controls.

If you dont want to use JFACE dialog buttons then override createButton(Composite parent, int id, String label, boolean defaultButton) to return null.

Answer (score -1):

You can use custom Stage window as a dialog and call `Stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);` method for it. Window will be blocked for its Application parent.

Comment: I am talking about javafx swt mixed app ..The solun u gave will work when it is pure javafx app